# Installing pecl and pear on OS X 10.11 El Capitan, macOS 10.12 Sierra, macOS 10.13 High Sierra (< 10.13.3)

Tags: php, macos, pear, pecl

So it looks like the new 'System Integrity Protection' [lockdown](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2015/09/os-x-10-11-el-capitan-the-ars-technica-review/8/) of /usr (among other directories) makes pear and pecl a non-starter. Has anyone found a workaround short of disabling it?

Comment: In the end, I disabled it, did what I needed to do, then re-enabled it.

Comment: How do you disable and renable it?

Comment: Here's a link to a Macworld article that describes how to enable and disable 'System Integrity Protection.' http://www.macworld.com/article/2986118/security/how-to-modify-system-integrity-protection-in-el-capitan.html

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There's a much easier way — no need to disable SIP or download your own copy:

```
sudo php /usr/lib/php/install-pear-nozlib.phar -d /usr/local/lib/php -b /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Took a while to accept because I didn't need this again until I installed Sierra and borked my whole LAMP stack (again).

Comment: This works great! But when I try to install an extension with `sudo pecl install` I get: `ERROR: failed to write /usr/lib/php/extensions/...` How can I get around this?

Comment: John: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584599/changing-pecl-installation-directory

Comment: What is -d and -b? Are they keys for phar file of for PHP?

Comment: Those are command-line flags specifying the path to (a) the PHP binary and (b) where pear should be installed.

Comment: This is not working with macOS High Sierra version 10.13.3 `Could not open input file: /usr/lib/php/install-pear-nozlib.phar`

Comment: Also not working for Mohave: `Could not open input file: /usr/lib/php/install-pear-nozlib.phar`

Comment: This should work

`curl -s -O https://pear.php.net/install-pear-nozlib.phar`

`sudo php install-pear-nozlib.phar -d /usr/local/lib/php -b /usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 61):

You shouldn't install binaries into system `/usr`, use `/usr/local` instead.

---

The `pecl` and `pear` commands should come along with PHP when installing via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Here is the example installing PHP with the latest Homebrew:

```
brew install php
```

or the specific version:

```
brew install php@7.1
brew install php@5.6
```

To find your `pecl` and `pear` commands, run:

```
find -L "$(brew --prefix php)" -name pecl -o -name pear
```

or:

```
find -L "$(brew --prefix php@7.1)" -name pecl -o -name pear
```

If you don't have it, consider uninstalling previous PHP version or run `reinstall` instead.

You can also try to relink it by:

```
brew unlink php@7.1 && brew link php@7.1 --dry-run && brew link --overwrite --force php@7.1
```

[Otherwise](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/213), link it manually:

```
ln -vs "$(find -L "$(brew --prefix php@7.1)/bin" -name pecl)" /usr/local/bin
ln -vs "$(find -L "$(brew --prefix php@7.1)/bin" -name pear)" /usr/local/bin
```

---

Alternatively download Pear it directly as a Phar package:

```
curl -o /usr/local/bin/pear http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/pear
```

or with this following one-liner (will work on Linux, but not on Unix):

```
curl -sL http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar | sudo install -v -m755 /dev/stdin /usr/local/bin/pear
```

Comment: @GregoryBell Thanks for a good catch. Installing PHP with `--with-pear` should install pear correctly (in `/usr/local/opt/php56/bin/pear`). Then `brew link php56` will link its binary to `/usr/local/bin/pear`.

Comment: I had to use `brew unlink php56 && brew link php56 --dry-run && brew link --overwrite php@5.6 --force` in order for it to work, I had an older php 5.5 install that had some conflicts.

Answer (score 52):

From this link: http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-pear-pecl-mac-os-x/ With this instructions, you don't need to disable 'System Integrity Protection'

> The following instructions install PEAR and PECL on Mac OS X under
>   **/usr/local/**. PECL is bundled with PEAR. So this is as simple as
>   installing PEAR on Mac OS X.
>
> PEAR is PHP’s Package Repository and makes it easy to download and
>   install PHP tools like PHPUnit and XDebug. I specifically recommend
>   these two for every PHP developer.
>
> ### Download PEAR
>
> ```
> curl -O https://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
> sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
> ```
>
> ### Configure and Install PEAR
>
> You should now be at a prompt to configure PEAR.
>
> 1. Type <kbd>1</kbd> and press <kbd>return</kbd>.
> 2. Enter:
>
>    ```
>    /usr/local/pear
>    ```
> 3. Type <kbd>4</kbd> and press <kbd>return</kbd>.
> 4. Enter:
>
>    ```
>    /usr/local/bin
>    ```
> 5. Press <kbd>return</kbd>
>
> ### Verify PEAR.
>
> You should be able to type:
>
> ```
> pear version
> ```
>
> Eventually, if you use any extensions or applications from PEAR, you
>   may need to update PHP’s include path.

Answer (score 7):

On Mohave I had to run the following commands - thanks go to https://tobschall.de/2018/08/07/pear-on-mojave/

```
cd /tmp
curl -s -O https://pear.php.net/install-pear-nozlib.phar
sudo php install-pear-nozlib.phar -d /usr/local/lib/php -b /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

High Sierra setup:

- install Brew
- install PHP with Brew

There is preinstalled PEAR PACKAGE in

```
/usr/local/opt/php@<your_version>/bin
```

from there you can run

```
pecl install xdebug
```

and you should have working PHP binary with Xdebug.

Comment: @frumbert I know it's probably really late but you can start script file from same folder using following syntax `./pecl install xdebug`. I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as of MacOS Sierra 10.12.1 for upgrading PHP, installing PEAR and V8

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php

phpversion="$(php -v | tail -r | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -c 1,3)"
brew unlink php$phpversion

brew install php71
brew install autoconf

curl -O  http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar

echo -e "\nexport PATH=$HOME/pear/bin:$PATH \n"

source ~/.bash_profile

echo -e "\ninclude_path = '.:/Users/YOURUSERNAME/pear/share/pear/' \nextension=v8js.so \n" >> /usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini

git clone https://github.com/phpv8/v8js ~/tmp/v8js && cd $_
./configure CXXFLAGS="-Wno-c++11-narrowing"
make
make test
make install

sudo apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Add suffix `--with-pear` to install pear and pecl
See example below

```
brew install php --with-pear
brew reinstall php --with-pear
```

Answer (score 0):

When brew is used and not linked, use:

```
brew install php@5.6
brew unlink php@5.6

$(brew --prefix php@5.6)/bin/pecl
$(brew --prefix php@5.6)/bin/pear
```

Answer (score 0):

So for big sur:

```
brew install php

brew services start php
```

Answer (score -1):

For macOS Mojave 10.14.4 just use /local instead of /usr when asked for "Installation base ($prefix)" location.