# Error installing pear in OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, pear

I try it to install pear following this instructions

```
curl -O http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
```

Then I set the Path and I type in terminal pear I get this message

```
 /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/bin/pear: line 28: /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.23/bin/php: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.30/bin/pear: line 28: exec: /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.23/bin/php: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Php was installed I few month ago with homebrew, I try several times and always I get the same error, there is not way to installed.

Comment: Run `set | grep PEAR` and see if there are variables that override the PHP location

Answer (score 0):

To make it consistent, you should install PHP and pear using the same method (via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)), e.g.:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install php56 pear
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer (thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/36547172/1953740) is to install brew with `--with-pear`:

`brew reinstall php56 --with-pear`

The `homebrew/science/pear` package mentioned in the other comment is not the PHP package manager; it's something different.

Answer (score 0):

fixing it by creating symlink,

For example, I have my php executable file in MacPorts so for me it will be like this:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/local/bin/php56 /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.23/bin/php
```

PS tested on macOS Hight Sierra 10.13.3, but it will work for El Capitan too